# Scalar product on Lie algebra of compact Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying Differential Geometry and I am facing with a lemma in which there is a step that I do not understand.
In particular, let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group, is used "$\langle\ \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ any $Ad(G)$-invariant scalar product (or equivalently a non-degenerate semi-positive bilinear form) on $\mathfrak{g}$, the Lie algebra of $G$ ". I can't find any such of scalar product.

When a connected compact Lie group $G$ has such a scalar product?
I tried with the Killing form that is semi-definite negative bilinear form, that is non-degenerate iff the lie algebra is semisimple, but how I can prove that a compact connected Lie group have semisimple Lie algebra?

I tried also with a proposition (3.6.2) in "lie groups", Duistermaat-Kolk, saying that the killing form of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is negative on the complement of the center $\mathfrak{z}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then if I prove that $G$ is centerless, so is $\mathfrak{g}$ and the opposite of the killing form is an $Ad(G)$-invariant scalar product on $\mathfrak{g}$.

$\underline{NOTE}$: The lemma I have to do states "Two maximal tori of a compact connected Lie group $G$ are coniugate", so we can suppose that $G$ is non-abelian.

Answer (score 3):

A compact Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ for a compact Lie group $G$ always admits an $Ad(G)$-invariant inner scalar product, see Propositioon $4.24$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=PAJmnm3DU1QC&pg=RA1-PA249&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). A compact Lie algebra need not be semisimple in general, but it is always reductive, i.e., a direct sum of the semisimple commutator ideal and the center. Hence the Killing form is negative semidefinite - see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra) for further references.

Comment: Thank you, the proof in the book you linked is very nice.
I thought that could be possible manage the Killing form to obtain a scalar product, but with 4.6 one can use compacteness for consider $G$ as a variety of measure 1 and define a scalar product on $V$ as the average of the scalar products in the integral, is this the structure, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the structure. The reference given by muzzlator at the duplicate link above is quite nice and could perhaps be helpful for you.